Why Spring returns response with status code 401 instead of 404?
I created new Java Spring app and added one controller with one method:
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}

When I'm trying to perform request GET /test I get response with no body and 401 status code.
In STDOUT of my Spring app I can see output:
WARN 36 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException: 404 NOT_FOUND]
Why I get 401 response instead of 404?

It's possible that your Spring Boot app is deferring to 401 Unauthorized due to security and/or CORS settings, which is taking precedence over your custom 404.  Do you currently get 401 on other routes as well?

Look into CROS Configuration or Add Spring [Security](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security) Configuration

If CROS Config, you can use
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedMethods("*")
            .allowedHeaders("*")
            .allowedOrigins("*");
        }
    };
}

or you can add @CrossOrigin to your endpoint
If Security Config in SecurityConfig class, you can use
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http
      .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
      .antMatchers("/test").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated() 
      )
       .csrf().disable();
   return http.build();
}

you can look into these methods
